# My App is live on play store but the play store is showing error "Your device isn't compatible with this version"

Tags: android

My App is live on play store but the play store is showing error

> Your device isn't compatible with this version

even the app is installing and working fine before uploading to play store in the same device.

Comment: in which phone you have open play store

Comment: share your Manifest file

Comment: there might be about 100 reasons of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check your gradle properties these two parameter and check your device meet with these sdk.

```
minSdkVersion 16
targetSdkVersion 23
```

this is example you have to check in your gradle properties what you set.